# binding multiple values in hibernate using play framework

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework

I am trying to build query in Play framework, I have

```
select * from Candidate c where (:schools member of c.schools)
```

After I bind :school with List with one element it returns result, but if I bind List with multiple elements nothing happens.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: {vector} [select c from models.Candidate c where (:schools0_, :schools1_ member of c.schools)  group by c.id order by RAND()]
```

Actually I need something like

```
select * from candidate where schools in (x,x,x,x,x);
```

Relation between candidate and school is in linked table.

Is there any way to bind multiple values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Hibernate, you can also use directly the list itself.

```
select c from Candidate c join c.schools as school where school.id in (:schools)
```

The type of the :schools parameter is typed according to your ids, for example `List<Int>` or `List<Long>`.

Answer (score 4):

Actually I found where the problem is - **member of** can be used only with single value and it works fine. When we need to use multiple values the best is to use standard sql **in**:

```
 select c from Candidate c inner join c.schools as school where school.id in (25980,25981)"
```

Joining the linked tables is required - we can't use c.schools.id, so we need to inner join c.schools with alias to specify the column.

I think all beginners should check http://www.javatx.cn/hibernate/reference/en/html/queryhql.html